# Assembly ContractNamespace doesn't seem to work?

Tags: wcf

I don't want to set the namespace for every single one of my data contracts so I decided to use the ContractNamespace attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs file of the project where my DataContracts reside. Here is the entry

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://www.mycompany.com/MyProject/", ClrNamespace = "Company.Project.Client.Entities")]
```

This does nothing. It seems I HAVE to specify the namespace on all the data contracts like so:

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.mycompany.com/MyProject/")]
```

..and yes, I have verified that my DataContracts are in fact in the specified ClrNamespace. Why doesn't this work? I'm using .net 4.5. Thanks.

---

**Update:** Here is the WSDL generated when I use explicit namespacing on the contract:

```
 <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:i0="http://www.company.com/Project/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AccountService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:import namespace="http://www.company.com/Project/" location="http://my.server.local/Project/Account/AccountService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
<wsdl:types/>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" type="i0:IAccountService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetByAccountNumber">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.company.com/Project/IAccountService/GetByAccountNumber" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="AccountService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService">
<soap:address location="http://my.server.local/Project/Account/AccountService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

And here is the WSDL I see when trying to use the ContractNamespace attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs

```
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AccountService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://my.server.local/Project/Account/AccountService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://my.server.local/Project/Account/AccountService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://my.server.local/Project/Account/AccountService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://www.company.com/Project/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://my.server.local/Project/Account/AccountService.svc?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Company.Project.Core"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IAccountService_GetByAccountNumber_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetByAccountNumber"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IAccountService_GetByAccountNumber_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetByAccountNumberResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IAccountService">
<wsdl:operation name="GetByAccountNumber">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IAccountService/GetByAccountNumber" message="tns:IAccountService_GetByAccountNumber_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IAccountService/GetByAccountNumberResponse" message="tns:IAccountService_GetByAccountNumber_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" type="tns:IAccountService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetByAccountNumber">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IAccountService/GetByAccountNumber" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="AccountService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService">
<soap:address location="http://my.server.local/Project/Account/AccountService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: "Does nothing".. in which scenario? How do you serialize the types?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm using EF on back end and have a DataContract attribute on the class, and a DataMember attribute on each property I want to send over the wire. I have ProxyCreationEnabled = false. Using the AssemblyInfo.cs ContractNamespace doesn't seem to set the namespace to all data contracts in that assembly

Comment: Where do you see the incorrect namespace? When you call a WCF service? In the DB?

Comment: When I create a proxy on the client and drill into its Endpoint > Contract > Namespace I see http://tempuri.org

Comment: I've also enabled tracing, and when looking at the .svclog I always see Processing action: http://tempuri.org/IMyService/MyMethod. The namespace from my assemblyInfo file isn't being picked up

Comment: Does your service project reference *and load* the correct DataContract assembly? (Check `typeof(OneOfYourDataContracts).Assembly.Location` in the service)

Comment: Are the correct namespaces exposed in the service's WSDL? Are you generating the client proxies against the correct WSDL?

Comment: How do I know if the proxies are using the correct WSDL? I also added to the OP.

Comment: Interesting... is the *only* difference really the [DataContract] namespace? You don't change anything in the service contract / operation contracts, do you? Can you provide a small repro project to download?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had two issues here. First was a typo in one of the ClrNamespace that I can't believe took me so long to notice. The second was that my Contracts were in a project, lets say Company.Project.Contracts. That project had a few folders, lets say Data and Service (for data and service contracts), and had some contracts in the namespace Company.Project.Contracts. Thus, in my AssemblyInfo.cs file, I had to have MULTIPLE ContractNamespace attributes like so:

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://www.company.com/Project/", ClrNamespace = "Company.Project.Business.Contracts")]
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://www.company.com/Project/", ClrNamespace = "Company.Project.Business.Contracts.Service")]
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://www.company.com/Project/", ClrNamespace = "Company.Project.Business.Contracts.Data")]
```

Also, @nodots, thanks for the pointers/help.

Comment: UGGGGHHH. This actually was NOT the solution. After removing all of the explicit namespacing and adding extra ContractNamespace entries, I could successfully transport data over the wire.. only just now I see that everything is in the tempuri namespace which is why it works. WTF.

Answer (score 0):

The ContractNamespace only applies to data contracts. You still have to set the service namespace on [ServiceContract].

The line

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://my.server.local/Project/Account/AccountService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://www.company.com/Project/"/>
```

in your WSDL indicates the ContractNamespace attribute does work.